# Use roswtf in continuous integration

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to setup a continuous integration on a GitLab repository to check whether my launch files are written correctly or not. `roswtf` looks the right tool to use fro my purpose, but if I print the exit code after running it it shows always zero (success), even when there are errors displayed.

Is there a way of analysing the results of `roswtf` - same as `catkin_test_results` does with the output of `catkin_make run_tests`? If not, can someone suggest me an alternative?

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392166/use-roswtf-in-continuous-integration/) by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> check whether my launch files are written correctly or not.

Depending on what you want to check though, there's [roslaunch-check](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#roslaunch-check). In my team we've been using it for awhile on Gitlab CI. While it's very nice tool, its error output (esp. on CI) may be unclear. I have some knowledge that I may have not yet shared publicly so ask again if you run into issues.

`roswtf`, which I'm a fan of, AFAIK doesn't come with `.launch` file checking? What's already available is more for static and dynamic checking of the system's state and doesn't include the checking for config files like `.launch` files IMO.
That doesn't mean you cannot implement a check using `roswtf`. You can write your own [plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf/Plugins). I'd usually recommend opening a pull request to the core library, but since you're on ROS Melodic, for which I don't think the maintainers take any new features, you'll be unlikely able to have it merged into the official core library though.

> Is there a way of analysing the results of `roswtf`

AFAIK `roswtf` was originally intended to print the result to `stdout` without any API, so what you get on stdout might be everything (I wish I am wrong but haven't found a way to programatycally interact with its output). I think I've tried to add API but I can't find a PR. Ayways, I'd answer as no to your question.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2021-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on 2021-12-08**:
Thanks, I did not know the existence of `roslaunch_check`. That looks like exactly what I was looking after.